# How to build superimposed UI in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What widgets can I use to make the interface look like this?

[image: Image example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simply cards ([Cards Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html)) with a Stack for one card on top of another ([Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)) and this plugin for the style: [flutter neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic)